# RSpec: NameError: uninitialized constant <MyControllerName>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller

I am new in RSpec and I'd just like to test my controller. I wrote my test that way:

```
RSpec.describe ServicesController do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "renders the index template" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template("index")
    end
  end
end
```

But my controller isn't recognized by RSpec, I get this error:

> NameError:   uninitialized constant ServicesController

In found examples I can find `require` line, which maybe could solve this problem, but as far as I can see, it concerns only files in `lib` folder, while my controller path is `app/controllers/services_controller.rb`. I tried to add it with path `../app/controllers/services_controller.rb`, going out from `lib` folder, but that doesn't work. What should I do? That's very basic case, but I wasn't able to find any help on the Web.

Comment: Did you run `rails generate rspec:install`?

Comment: No, I ran only `bin/rspec --init`, like shown in main page of RSpec. Is it outdated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may miss require `rails_helper` at the beginning of your specs:

```
require 'rails_helper'
```

Comment: I tried it also, but I got `LoadError: cannot load such file -- rails_helper`. Should I create a file named `rails_helper`? If so, what should it contain?

Comment: Are you using this gem `https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails`?  After install it, run this command `bundle exec rails generate rspec:install` and it automatically generate necessary files for you.

Comment: Okay, you're right, I was using wrong gem, now everything works perfectly :)